# How to download files over HTTP via python-urllib2 correctly?

Tags: python, image, file

I've written parser on python to download images from Internet:

```
import urllib2

for i in xrange(1,10):
  r = urllib2.urlopen('http://example.com/'+str(i)+'.gif'))
  f = open('C:\\' + str(i) + '.gif', 'w+')
  f.write(r.read())
  f.close()
```

Images can't be opened. Windows says 'Error while building image'. But I've found that every line of received file less on 1 byte than this line of original file, but both look similar. How to download correct file?

Comment: On Windows you need to specify 'wb', not 'w+'

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When working with windows you may need to put the "binary" flag `b` in open...

```
f = open(r'C:\\'+str(i)+'.gif','wb')
```

Answer (score 5):

On Windows you need to specify 'wb', not 'w+'

Answer (score 4):

You can try [urllib.urlretrieve](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve) - it handles most of details by itself.
So your code will look like this:

```
for i in xrange(1,10):
    urllib.urlretrieve('http://example.com/'+str(i)+'.gif'), 'C:\'+str(i)+'.gif','w+')
```